# 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solution' in VS hangs when checking ProGet feed

Tags: nuget-server, proget

In Visual Studio, when using *Manage NuGet Packages for Solution*, the ProGet feeds never return.  Visual Studio just hangs.  No updates from the feed are ever delivered.  When using *Manage NuGet Packages* at the project level, the ProGet feeds work great and are nice and quick.

Any resolution to this problem?  It's the only issue preventing full usage of ProGet.

*Update:*
*I'm now happily working with the ProGet team on this issue.*

Comment: This appears to only happen on solutions that have a large quantity of projects.  With a large solution of 24 projects, solution level nuget package management does not work.

Comment: I am also noticing this on an individual project within a very large solution.  It's only the Updates that do not work via Package Manager dialog, available packages on the feed (Online in VS) works fine.

Comment: This may have been an issue related to NuGet "batch" queries, and if that's the case, it should already be resolved in the v4.5.0 (beta) version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProGet v3.5.x version has resolved the issue.